# How to use triangulate from the library triangle in python

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, triangulation, delaunay, concave-hull

I want to detect the boundary of my set of points. I tried Delaunay triangulation from scipy spatial, but I get this:[image]

And when I perform alpha shape from those triangles, I can't get the boundary of the set of points. So I think that I should use constrained Delaunay triangulation. I choose the triangle library to perform this. But the trouble is that I don't know what to feed to the function triangle.triangulate(tri, opts=''). I feed all my set of points that I change into dictionary but it returns my set of points. So anyone can help me to use this function or another alternative to perform the contour detection? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use another library for my purpose: [shapely](https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html).
Here is how to use it to triangulate a concave object:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
from shapely.ops import triangulate
points=MultiPoint(data)
triangles = triangulate(points)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the triangle library, but you can use an alternative to perform  this.

It is a widespread problem, and you can get a simple code to solve this.
This problem, in the algorithms, is also known as Convex hull, and there is a class available in scipy.

The code follows below, with the comments.

```
#imports
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Init graphics
axis = plt.gca(); axis.cla();

#Get points sample
points = np.random.rand(20, 2)

#get Convex hull instance for the points set
hull = ConvexHull(points)

#plor the points
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'v')

#Get and plot the boundary
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    axis.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'r-')
```

The result graph can be seen soon after:

[image]

REFs:

- http://www.qhull.org/
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5426/finding-boundary-co-ordinates-from-given-set-of-point-co-ordinates

Comment: I used this library before but my shape is concave not convex, that's why the convex hull did not give me what I wanted. Shapely library performs better the task.